# Hide and show a div inside vue.js template for selected item only?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have an array of songs and inside the template I have an icon to toggle between show/hide of a div. It works when clicked and it expands the div but it expands the div for every item in the array (no matter which song is clicked). I would like it to only expand the div of the clicked item. Do I need to link it the id variable somehow? Here is the code:

This is in the html template:

```
<div class="dropdown-icon" title="Show/Hide Description" 
@click="toggleShowDescription">
<i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-dropdown-circle"></i>
</div>

<div :class="showDescription?'show':'hide'" v-if="showDescription">
<p class="song-description">{{song.description}}</p>
```

This what I have in the JS concerning the hide/show div element:

```
    songs: [

        {
        id: 1,
        title: "Track 1",
        description: "Description 1",
        url: "",
        keywords:"",
        genre:"",
        moods:"",
        tempo:"",
        theme:"",
      },

      {
        id: 2,
        title: "Track 2",
        description: "Description 2",
        url:"",
        keywords: "",
        genre:"",
        moods:"",
        tempo:"",
        theme:"",
      },
],

showDescription: false,
  },

methods: {

    toggleShowDescription() {
      this.showDescription = !this.showDescription;
    },

},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the value of showDescription for every single song. The best bet would be to create an array that tracks which song descriptions are showing and then add/remove items as the toggle button is clicked.

For the template...

```
<div class="dropdown-icon" title="Show/Hide Description" 
@click="toggleShowDescription(song)">
<i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-dropdown-circle"></i>
</div>

<div :class="showDescription?'show':'hide'" v- 
if="songsDisplayingDescription.indexOf(song.id) !== -1">
<p class="song-description">{{song.description}}</p>
```

and then the script...

```
  songsDisplayingDescription: [],
},
methods: {
  toggleShowDescription(song) {
    const songId = song.id;
    const indexOfSongId = this.songsDisplayingDescription.indexOf(songId);

    if (indexOfSongId !== -1) {
      this.songsDisplayingDescription.splice(indexOfSongId, 1);
      return;
    }

    this.songsDisplayingDescription.push(songId);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Mike, thank you for answering! However, I can't get this to work. What I am looking for is to keep all of the songs in the array displayed but show and hide the description on the clicked song's drop down icon. Here is an example of the code: https://codepen.io/parca0007/pen/gyjdxK - notice how all of the descriptions show when clicked. I only want the one description to show.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that the drop down is for mobile versions so you'll need to shrink the window to below 1000px for it to show up.

Comment: I got it working on https://codepen.io/miketalley/pen/VNBEEN -- I would highly suggest looking further into components(https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html). Your code would benefit greatly from breaking things up a bit.

Comment: Yes, I will definitely look at breaking it up into different components eventually. I have only just started with javascript and have no background in coding so it is probably a big mess to someone who knows what they are doing! haha. Once again, thank you for helping me out!